# calling class instance methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Im new to ruby and I am currently learning classes.

If I were to have a class

```
class Book
  private
  def BookTitle
    puts "this books title"
  end
end

a = Book.new
a.BookTitle
```

`produces a NoMethodError`

Is the only way I can access class methods is with this line?

`attr_accessor :BookTitle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `BookTitle` is not defined as a class method.

To define a class method, you prefix the method name with `self.` (there are also other methods, though perhaps not worth worrying about for now). However, I think you are referring to instance methods rather than class methods.

You cannot directly call your BookTitle method because you have defined it as a private method. If you remove the `private` line in your example, you can call the method without any difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

your method is private, thus you can not access it in global scope (see this irb extract):

```
irb(main):001:0> class Book
irb(main):002:1>   private
irb(main):003:1>   def BookTitle
irb(main):004:2>     puts "this books title"
irb(main):005:2>   end
irb(main):006:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):007:0>
irb(main):008:0* a = Book.new
=> #<Book:0x105ceb8>
irb(main):009:0> a.BookTitle
NoMethodError: private method `BookTitle' called for #<Book:0x105ceb8>
        from (irb):9
        from D:/dev/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):010:0>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set BookTitle to be a `private` method. A `private` method is one that can only be called within the class itself or by instances of the class (there are exceptions). If you take the `private` out, it should work.

Some side notes: Ruby convention has method names as lower-case, with words separated by underscores, so you should name your method `book_title`.

Also, small secret, Ruby's private methods aren't so private, you could call `a.send("BookTitle")` and it would work.

Answer (score 1):

You have set

```
private
```

on the second line which is what is preventing you from accessing this method. You could declare the method above the private line and it would be public.